# AUAudioUnit getting host sample rate changes

Tags: audiounit

Just a simple quick question, how do I can know about AudioUnit host application changes to sample rate?

My custom **AUAudioUnit v3** subclass seems not to have any property to observe and **AUHostMusicalContextBlock** do not provide a sample rate inspection.

I need to react for sample rate changes in host application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe a safe place to do it is in allocateRenderResourcesAndReturnError. e.g.,

```
mySampleRate = self.outputBus.format.sampleRate;
```

This is where Apple's iOSFilterDemoApp does it

Comment: It seems this is not the answer. In Apple's AUv3Filter demo, `outputBus`'s `sampleRate`(44100) was set by and hard coded in the "Adapter". I'm still looking for a way to get the host's sample rate.

Comment: I would like to see this too, as I am unable to inspect when a sample rate of project changes